# Get stack trace from uncaught exception?

Tags: c++, windows, exception, stack-trace

I realise this will be platform specific: is there any way to get a stack trace from an uncaught C++ exception, but from the point at which the exception is thrown?

I have a Windows Structured Exception Handler to catch access violations, etc. and generate a minidump. But of course that won't get called in the event of termination due to an uncaught C++ exception, and so there is no crash dump.

I'm looking for a Windows solution at the moment (no matter how dirty!), but would like to hear about other platforms if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We implemented MiniDumps for unhandled exceptions in our last title using the information from this site:

[http://beefchunk.com/documentation/sys-programming/os-win32/debug/www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps.html](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps.html)

And to catch the unhandled exceptions on windows have a look at:

SetUnhandledExceptionFilter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28VS.85%29.aspx).

As an aisde, we spent a lot of time experimenting with the different levels of minidump until we settled on one. This proved to be of no real use in real world crashes as we had no idea what they would be at the time the minidumps were implemented. It's very application specific, and also crash specific, so my recommendation is to add the minidump handler as early as possible, it will grow with the project and through QA and it will be a life saver at somepoint (and hopefully out in the real world too).

Comment: This does work for uncaught C++ exceptions (well, for apps built with Visual Studio). My original misunderstanding was due to a hidden catch(...) block in the depths of a library somewhere...!

Comment: A good article! You use MiniDumpWriteDump(GetCurrentProcess()...) but MSDN says that MiniDumpWriteDump() should be called from a separate process or at least from a separate thread. Does your code not lead to a wrong stacktrace?

Comment: The stracktraces we were getting were correct, but this was 10 years ago so I can’t verify if that was fluke or the functions had different requirements back then. Let us know how you get on, I would be keen to update the answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [try-except Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28VS.80%29.aspx) to "convert" a C++ exception to a structured exception (out of which you can then get a nice stack trace). Consider this:

```
// Your function to get a backtrace from a CONTEXT
const char *readBacktrace( CONTEXT &ctx );

extern "C"
static DWORD exceptFilter( struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS* exInf )
{
    OutputDebugStringA( readBacktrace( *exInf->ContextRecord ) );
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

try {
  // your C++ code which might yield exceptions
} catch ( ... ) {
  // In case a C++ exception occurs, raise a structured exception and catch it    immediately
  // so that we get a CONTEXT object which we can use to generate a stack trace.
  __try {
    RaiseException( 1, 0, 0, NULL );
  } __except( exceptFilter( GetExceptionInformation() ) ) {
  }
}
```

This is a little clumsy, but the nice thing is that you can put the __try { } __except() { } part into a general purpose `dumpStackTrace()` function. You can then yield stack traces from any point in your program, as you like.

Comment: that code doesn't really compile as you can't use __try/__except inside try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

Try using set_terminate to install terminate handler. And in it grab stack trace using mini dump funcitons. Maybe it will work.

Comment: This is exactly what I do, based on this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/debug/XCrashReportPt1.asp